# Router slower when wired compared to wireless

Tags: wifi

Apologies if this is not the right place for this question.

We have an Ajax web app.

At a user's site, they were having trouble running this application. It appeared that the internet was slow as they also had problems with normal browsing. Their PC was wired to the router.

I connected my laptop wirelessly to the same router and everything worked fine, which pointed to a problem with their computer.

Apparently not, they replaced the router and the problem was gone. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

There could be a cable or router connector problem which won't be the case with wireless.

Comment: Good point. Wood through the trees...

Comment: My first thought would have been to check the cable and the router port (as the ports themselves seem to go bad after some period of time on consumer grade routers)

Comment: Maybe someone put a phone cable into the socket, bending some of the pins in there.

Answer (score 3):

Wireless 802.11g is faster than 10Base-T.  Maybe the first router autonegotiated 10Base-T instead of 100Base-T for some reason?  It used to happen a lot with cheap switches and NICs that didn't do autonegotiation right, and so we used to turn off autonegotiation to force everybody to the same settings.

Comment: This was my first thought, router on half duplex and the computer on full duplex.  It doesn't seem to appear much anymore, but 5-10 years ago it was the first thing I'd look for with usually slow network connections.

Comment: I have a switch that will go down to 10Base-T after a brown-out.

Answer (score 0):

A consumer-grade "router" is actually a lot of separate devices rolled into one. It is a wireless access point, a switch, a router, usually also a firewall and DHCP server at least. It is possible that the switch portion was going bad, but the AP portion was functioning fine (assuming there were no physical network problems like a bad cable).